# For which values of $k$, we have $A = A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got this question in hw. Can anyone help me solve it?

Let

$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
k & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & k \end{array} \right) $

For which values of $k$, we have $A = A^{-1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Compute $A\cdot A{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$A = A^{-1} \Rightarrow A^2 = I$$

Compute $A^2$ and impose that it has to be equal to $I$

Answer (score 1):

$A^2=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
k^2+1 & 0 & 2k \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
2k & 0 & k^2+1 \end{array} \right]\stackrel{!}=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$, thus we must have $k=0$.

Comment: Why are you giving complete solutions to homework?

Comment: is that bad etiquette?  have only been on here a couple of weeks

Comment: @ellya it is not bad etiquette but if you fully answer very simple questions it is likely that you do more harm than good to the asker.